# Rails API best practice for rendering params of referenced table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm using a rails API with a React frontend. My Scores table has a course_id column via a foreign key

```
class CreateScores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :scores do |t|
      t.integer :score
      t.float :differential
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :course, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :rating
      t.integer :slope

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my React app I want to be able to render the name of a specified course not just the id provided by the course_id column - so something like 'Augusta National' rather than '18'.

I'm not sure of the best practice to accomplish this. I've tried to add a column to my Score table that references the Course :name column but have failed miserably - I've also tried pulling the name of the course in a private method in the Score controller and merging it into the create method but this has also failed - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your models associated like:

```
# app/models/score.rb
class Score < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
end


# app/models/course.rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scores
end
```

You'll be able to render any course info you like along with your score in your json views:

```
# app/views/scores/_score.json.jbuilder
json.extract! score, :id, :score # etc...

json.course do
  json.name score.course.try(:name)
end


# app/views/scores/show.json.jbuilder
json.partial! 'scores/score', score: @score
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to solve a number of issue but instead of using jbuilder I utilized the active_model_serializer gem. I added a has_one: course association to score_serializer.rb

```
class ScoreSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :strokes, :user_id, :differential, :created_at, :updated_at
  has_one :course
  has_one :user
end
```

so now the json that my frontend receives has a course object

```
{
    "strokes": 81,
    "user_id": 1,
    "differential": null,
    "created_at": "2018-03-11T17:49:12.432Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-03-11T17:49:12.432Z",
    "course": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Timberlin White",
        "rating": 71,
        "slope": 120,
        "created_at": "2018-03-09T17:37:37.165Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-15T01:19:37.113Z"
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mookie",
        "created_at": "2018-03-08T18:50:51.703Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-03-15T01:17:33.417Z"
    }
},
```

and in my react app I access to any attribute of the associated course object - this.state.score.course.name => 'Timberlin White'